# SWIFTUI TextView with real-time, programmatically-appendable text

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm looking for a way to create a simple textview (command line like) that will show the user what is going on inside the app. It should be able to append elements programmatically in real time so user can monitor and copy text from it. Im writing app for macOS.

So far i done this:

```
class OutputElementStruct: Identifiable
{
    var HEX: String
    var Balance: String

    init(HEX: String, Balance: String)
    {
        self.HEX = HEX
        self.Balance = Balance
    }
}

class OutputElements: ObservableObject
{
    @Published var OutputElement = [OutputElementStruct]()

    init()
    {
        self.OutputElement =
        [
            OutputElementStruct(HEX: "sometext", Balance: "sometext")
        ]
    }
}
```

Then it shows to user

```
struct OutputView: View
{

@StateObject var OutputArray = OutputElements()

var body: some View
{
    GeometryReader
    { Geo in
        ZStack
        {
            BoxView(width: 600, height: 700, Name: "")
            
            VStack
            {
                List
                {
                    ForEach($OutputArray.OutputElement)
                    { item in
                        Text(verbatim: item.HEX.wrappedValue)
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    .frame(width: 600, height: 700, alignment: .center)
}
}
```

and here is data added.

```
@StateObject var OutputArray = OutputElements()

.onTapGesture 
{
    print("button tapped")
    OutputArray.OutputElement.append(OutputElementStruct(HEX: "sometext", Balance: "sometext"))                     
}
```

It is working, but not in real time. While i tapped the button it is prints "button tapped" in Xcode, but text view does not displays anything except firstly added item in `init()`. So how to make it work?

Comment: Since it is onAppear all you have to do to make it work likely is delay it with DispatchQueue async after. Also, submit a bug through feedback assistant

Comment: Can this be a bug? Im using Xcode Version 13.0 beta 3 (13A5192j)

Comment: Yes it seems to be happening more often in iOS 15. It doesn’t seem natural that you would have to delay something onAppear. I’ve seen it most often with updating text fields and the tracking transparency pop up, there are other instances too but these seem to be the most common. The transparency thing was definitely with iOS 15 many people got their apps rejected per SO posts right after it came out because their pop up was suddenly not showing.

Comment: Wait, didn't get where I need to add delay? Since it is swiftui Xcode tell's me that type '()' doesn't confirm to 'View', I have updated code to full page as it is now.

Comment: Caleb posted the right answer below. You have two instances of your object

Answer (score 0):

> While i tapped the button it is prints "button tapped" in Xcode, but text view does not displays anything except firstly added item in init(). So how to make it work?

It looks like you've got two separate arrays that are both named `OutputArray`, and the one you're appending objects to isn't the one that your view is displaying. That's why you don't see any new objects show up even though you know you're adding them.

You need a single array that's used in both places. I think you've got the right idea by using `@StateObject`, but instead of creating *two* `@StateObject` variables, create just one and add it to the environment as explained in the [`StateObject` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject).